# Unable to install yarn

Tags: yarnpkg

I installed node v16.15.1, npm v8.12.2   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE2u3.png)

```
$  npm install -g yarn
```

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/yarn/-/yarn-1.22.19.tgz - not_found

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  'yarn@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/yarn/-/yarn-1.22.19.tgz' is not in this registry.

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-25T07_47_50_510Z-debug-0.log